# Why are the properties files missing in the target directory after compilation in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, properties-file

Some time ago I switched from Eclipse 4.7.3 EE-Edition to Eclipse 4.27 Standard-Edition. Since then I have had problems with the properties files. It happens from time to time that when I start a Springboot application, for example, I get the error that the required properties files could not be loaded. When I then look at the target folders, the properties files are missing.
Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause? I have a slight suspicion that it could be related to a plug-in that is included in the EE edition and is now missing in the standard edition.

Under Eclipse 4.7.3 EE-Edition I never had the problem. Typically, the problem occurs after the initial checkout, i.e. when Eclipse compiles the code for the first time. However, it can also occur during operation. In other words, I start the application and everything is fine. Then I make a few changes to the code and restart the application and suddenly the problem with the properties files occurs.

The problem can usually be solved by recompiling the code completely (*Eclipse menu* -> *Project* -> *Clean...*) or/and "Maven update" (*context menu* -> *Maven* -> *Update Project...*). Sometimes you have to repeat the steps several times, sometimes one of them is enough.

I am very grateful for any tips/hints, as this behaviour is extremely annoying and time-consuming, Szdnez

Comment: In a SpringBoot application, the properties files should be within the compressed jar/war file. Can you check if they are there? And also can you put some maven logs when you don't see them?

Comment: I did not change anything in the way how I work. Mainly I do not compile the code with Maven or start the Sprinboot-app with Maven. Mainly Eclipse does the compiling (however Eclipse does it in the backround) and afterwards I directly start the app. So Maven is mainly used to handle the dependencies. When the problem will occur the next time, I will also have a look into the jar files.

Comment: Also, where are your properties files located in the source tree? Are they somewhere in the `src/main/java` folder or are they in `src/main/resources`?  Because `src/main/resources` is where they are actually supposed to be

Comment: Most of the Java projects in my workspace are still using the classical structure with `src` and `test`. Some of them are using the Maven structure and there all properties files are located under `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 0):

In a maven project you can control what resources are included within your build by using the `<resource>` tag like this:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Note that `src/main/resources` is the default folder for all your resources, and if you wish to have some resources included in your build and some not, you can leave the default folder out and use another one to be included, for example:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/runtime</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Like this, everything you put in src/main/resources/runtime will be included in your build under /classes/ folder, and everything else under src/main/resources will be left out.
For more details see [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/).
You may want to look there at maven filtering as well, it is often used in conjunction with resources.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of it. My workspace consists of many Java projects. Most of them are still using the classical structure with `src` and `test`, some of them are using the Maven structure. Maybe this can also be an issue. But what makes me curious is, that it was also the same setup with the working Eclipse 4.7. From 4.7 to 4.27 I did not change anything like this, only the Eclipse version and suddenly the problem occured. And I also do not have any problems building the app with pure Maven in the CI/CD-environment. It is just a problem in combination with Eclipse.