# What is the meaning of bin and target directories in the Eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse

I am still dealing with the problem [Why are the properties files missing in the target directory after compilation in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77543215/why-are-the-properties-files-missing-in-the-target-directory-after-compilation-i).

That's why I'm taking another look at the project structure in the Eclipse workspace. I am currently using Eclipse 4.27 Standard Edition and use Maven to resolve dependencies etc. I have been wondering for some time that the project structures of the individual projects in the workspace look different. All projects have a generated `target` directory. However, some projects also have a generated `bin` directory, which in turn includes a `target` directory.

What I don't understand is where does the `bin` directory come from? In both cases, the `.classpath` file looks the same. Can the two directories influence each other? Are there any dependencies between them?

I have not yet been able to find anything in the Eclipse configuration that I could consider to be the cause of the `bin` directory. You can define an output folder under `Java -> Build Path`. According to the description, however, this is only the default setting when creating new projects. Nevertheless, I have set it to `target`, which, as expected, has no influence on the existing projects.

Comment: bin is the default java compile output folder. target is the default maven project output folder

Comment: `bin` is configured in the "Source" tab of the "Java Build Path" in the Project Properties.

Comment: That's why I wrote alls projects have the same `.classpath` file ("source" project properties are stored in `.classpath`). My question is, why most of my project in the workspace does not have a `bin` folder and some projects have it? And can it lead into unexpected issues? Or do they exists side by side without any problems?